# Help me rescue my bland soup

Tags: soup, seasoning

Help I threw in carrot,  potato,  parsnip, turnip, leek and two ham stock cubes but I've ruined it by using to much water and I've already blended it.   I would really hate to have to chuck it in the bin.  Any suggestions on how to rescue the flavour and thickness? Added a little paprika and coriander earlier still very bland.

Answer (score 10):

If too much water is the culprit, then its a simple matter of reducing the soup on the stove top. Just put it in a pot and boil it with the lid off(so the water escapes) until you reached a desired thickness and flavor.

Comment: Thanks jay I'll try that just now been awhile since I cooled from memory usually uae recipes

Answer (score 3):

Thickness is actually easy to deal with (assuming you're trying to thicken it) :

- Take a potato, peel it, then grate it.  Add the grated potato to the soup, and let it cook 'til it breaks down fully.

... or you could use instant potato flakes.

For the blandness, if you have time, see [an earlier question on the topic](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/12500/67).  If you need an immediate
fix and don't want to wait for things to cook down, I find acid works best (a shot of vinegar or sherry, a squeeze of lime or lemon juice, or a dab of sour cream; exact type depends on the cuisine you're going for; add just before serving).

Also consider adding extra salt (possibly in the form of bullion) and pepper (any type -- crushed red, black, paprika).

Answer (score 1):

Add miso paste to boost the savory (umami) flavor. I have had success with "white" miso in carrot and lighter, brothy vegetable and pork soups; red miso in beef soups. Asian fish sauce is another high octane umami booster, but you have to cook off it's funkiness and it's salty, so use sparingly at first.